# What are some good code searching web interfaces?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, django

I'm looking for a good web framework/plugin/what have you that greps over a specific codebase.

I've done many searches for something like this including on GitHub and Google code and haven't found what I'm looking for...

Specifically I would like something that can index my code and present a Web UI to search over said codebase for class names, function names or just free text and regexes.

Ideally I could run the indexers at set intervals with cron and maybe the same script could even refresh the code from Git automatically before re-indexing, presenting an always fresh view of my code in the same Web UI.

Phabricator offers code browsing but no code search as far as I can tell.

This should also allow to browser code from the search results.

Are there open source options for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Java, I've had [some luck](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/01/18/using-lucene-to-search-java-source.html) using [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org) to index source code.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that but that definitely requires me to do some work. Could be a fun side project, but I was hoping to not have to do much config work...

Answer (score 0):

[Krugle for Git and github](http://www.krugle.com/krugle-git.php) may be worth a look.